# How to change STUN server in sipJS

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip, stun

I'm in a deadend here, I have searched API reference, google and stackoverflow but can't find answer I'm looking for.

How can I change on what stun server to use in sipJS-0.19

In earlier versions of sipJS and JsSip, I can do this

```
var callOptions = {
    mediaConstraints: {
      audio: true,
      video: true
    },
    pcConfig: {
        iceServers: [
            { urls: ["stun:my.stun.server.com"] }
        ],
        iceTransportPolicy: "all"
    }
  };
```

And I have tried this in the latest sipJS

```
sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions: {
            constraints: { audio: true, video: false },
                peerConnectionConfiguration: {
                    iceServers: [{
                        urls:"stun:my.stun.server.com"
                    }],
                    'iceTransportPolicy': "all"
                }
            }
        });
```

And this still shows in the console the default stun.

```
iceServers:[{urls:"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}],iceTransportPolicy:"all"
```

I have tried changing **peerConnectionConfiguration** to **rtcConfiguration**

Or adding it to the userAgentOptions, still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

As per the current version of sip.js right now (0.20.0), this can be achieved through the `UserAgentOptions.sessionDescriptionHandlerFactoryOptions.peerConnectionConfiguration` options.

The full schema for the options are:

```
bundlePolicy: "balanced", // Note: max-bundle is not supported by the demo backend currently (5/15/17)
certificates: undefined,
iceCandidatePoolSize: 0,
iceServers: [{ urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }], // TURN URL example: "turn:88.88.88.0:3478", "test", "test"
iceTransportPolicy: "all",
peerIdentity: undefined,
rtcpMuxPolicy: "require"
```

So, to turn off ice servers for your UserAgent, simply add

```
var agent = new UserAgent({
   //... other options
   sessionDescriptionHandlerFactoryOptions: {
      iceGatheringTimeout: 500, //currently, the smallest allowed value
      peerConnectionConfiguration: {
        iceServers: []
      }
    }
});
```

To confirm this, grab an "Established" (Invitation.state) Invitation object (from an incoming call), then look at the `sessionDescriptionHandler.sessionDescriptionHandlerConfiguration.peerConnectionConfiguration.iceServers` value and you should see the empty list set above.